# Error: The xxx module cannot be found

Tags: read-the-docs

I'm tring to build this [doc](https://github.com/buxx/synergine/tree/master/doc) (conf.py in doc/source/conf.py) on **readthedocs.org**. Build fail (full trace [here](https://readthedocs.org/builds/synergine/2840465/)):

```
html
-----

Error: The 'pytz.lazy' module cannot be found. Did you install Sphinx and its dependencies correctly?
```

I try to [WIPE the build environnement](http://docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#deleting-a-stale-or-broken-build-environment) but with no success. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assure you check the "system package usage" option in Advanced settings.